# Run a lot of similar parse servers on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I have been running a lot of similar parse server apps on AWS Elastic Beanstock. I do not need a lot of computing power just a way to run a lot of parse servers on AWS without having to pay for a separate server for each one. Would there be a way to run multiple apps on one of the parse servers or would there be a way to put multiple parse servers on one instance somehow in Elastic Beanstock? An example of the kind of server I am running can be found at the [Parse GitHub page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is by putting each parse-server app into its own docker container and then deploying a bunch of different containers on a single "beanstalk" each running on their own port.

In some cases I use the same code base for multiple apps and in some the code is different. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/config to manage configuration in all cases, but in cases where the code is the same, I use the env var `NODE_APP_INSTANCE` to have different config value for different apps.

simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and a simple `Dockerrun.aws.json`

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [ ],
  "containerDefinitions":
    [
      {
        "name": "app1",
        "image": "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/boo/app1:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 1536,
        "entryPoint": ["node", "index.js"],
        "portMappings":
          [
            {
              "hostPort": 9091,
              "containerPort": 9091
            }
          ],
        "environment":
        [
          {
            "name": "NODE_ENV",
            "value": "production"
          }
        ]
     },
     {
        "name": "app2",
        "image": "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/boo/app2:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 512,
        "entryPoint": ["node", "index.js"],
        "portMappings":
          [
            {
              "hostPort": 9092,
              "containerPort": 9092
            }
          ],
        "environment":
        [
          {
            "name": "NODE_ENV",
            "value": "production"
          },
          { "name": "NODE_APP_INSTANCE",
            "value": "app2"
          }
        ]
     },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there an example of how this works? I have never used Docker.

Comment: Good question.  The basics are: make a container.  put on AWS ECS.  Tell Beanstalk where your container is.

Here are three links that run through those three steps

How to dockerize a node app: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

putting a container on ecs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

deploying a docker container to elasticbeanstalk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html